# Is there any reason to use dict instead of defaultdict?

Tags: python, dictionary

The title says it all:

**Is there any reason to use dict instead of [defaultdict](http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict)?**

The only reason I can think of is "I really don't need it". But then I could ask if there is any reason why dict is not replaced by defaultdict.

Possible reasons might be:

- Loss of performance
- Testing

But I don't think that the performance loss is so bad, because you only have to check if a new value is already present which is amortized in O(1).

I also can't think of examples where testing might get more difficult. (But I'm not very experienced)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Plenty of reasons **not** to use a `defaultdict`:

- if your values are not homogenous and thus cannot be generated by a simple factory function.
- if you *need* missing keys to raise an exception instead of creating a new value for you automatically.
- If all your default values require more context than the factory function receives; the factory function has no access to the key being inserted, for example.

`defaultdict` fills a specialized use-case, where you *want* values to be auto-created for you when a key is missing, and those values can be generated with a factory function without access to key being inserted.

Note that exceptions are *not* just there to flag programmer error. Exceptions are a tremendously powerful part of the Python language useful for far more than just coding errors. If your data is *usually* not going to need a new key, then using exception handling (asking for forgiveness) is faster than testing for the key each time (asking for permission).

See [Python Forgiveness vs. Permission and Duck Typing](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/175663) over on Progammers for a comparison.

Comment: Why would you want that? Shouldn't you then check before if the key is present? Isn't an exception that you can avoid a sign that the programmer did something wrong?

Comment: @moose: No, exceptions are **not** just for programmer errors.

Comment: Another reason: if you need to support Python 2.4 or earlier.

Comment: @moose: Exceptions are an out-of-band signal, to signify an exceptional situation, and a good programmer can use that signal in very effective (and performant) ways.

Comment: @MartijnPieters: Thanks for the link! I knew that there are legimate uses for exceptions like IO, but I thought when you can prevent them, you should do that.